# Translate "Beautiful woman, my beautiful woman"

Tags: translation

I've come up with "Bella donna, la mia bella donna". The phrase is used in this sense: My beautiful woman, why did you go?

The translation must fit into musical notes in that phrasing: 4 notes, then 7 notes. All advice is warmly appreciated!

Comment: With all the respect for this site's users, me among them, perhaps a professional En>It translator could help you more than a piecemeal, crowdsourced translation?

Comment: Every pro I've found specializes in technical, legal, medical, etc. I would happily hire someone who I feel has an artistic/poetic bent rather than a purely business orientation. That's how I ended up here: looking for someone who will find the task interesting, rather than someone who gets paid by the word and is in a hurry.

Comment: Perhaps with an inversion: “Donna bella, la mia bella donna”.

Answer (score 2):

I won't translate it literally; "bella donna, la mia bella donna" is more or less right, but it sounds rather tone-deaf to me.

Since it has to be 4 syllables / 7 syllables, I'd go with

> Mio splendore, mia donna rara e bella (my splendor, my rare and beautiful woman)

I'll update this answer as I come up with more possible translations.